# Redis - List Keys by size

Tags: redis

Is there a way to get a report from Redis with columns Key and Size?

Answer (score 4):

You can get the big keys with this command

```
redis-cli --bigkeys
```

In your `redis-cli` run this command to get the Key length

```
DEBUG OBJECT <key>
```

above command returns  `serializedlength` which may be you are looking for.

Comment: im using redis desktop manager... it's console tells me that the command is invalid...

Comment: @Leonardo on which platform you are?

Comment: A better alternative as of v4 is `MEMORY USAGE <key>`

Comment: @laravellevaral i'm using Azure redis cache... it recognizes several commands, but --bigkeys doesnt stick...

Comment: @Leonardo try `MEMORY USAGE <key>` as mentioned by itamer in comments

Comment: isn't that for a single key?

Comment: @Leonardo You can use  wildcard `MEMORY USAGE *`

Comment: @Leanardo I am 100% above given all commands are wrking for me

Comment: i managed to get --bigkeys going, is there a way to point it to `dbN`? right now it's not finding any keys...

Comment: `dbN` no idea about it

Comment: C:\Users\Administrator>redis-cli -h MyCache1.redis.cache.windows.net -p 1234
-a password MEMORY USAGE *

Comment: @laravellevaral by dbN i mean, db0, db1, db2... db15

Comment: @Leonardo you want to get the size of redis db?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166988/discussion-between-leonardo-and-laravel-levaral).

Comment: @adnan-mumtaz there a way to get the biggest KEY (an error made a really large key with garbage in the name; the value is small) and delete it?

Comment: @MichaelJohnston  This is something that can be done with Programming.